# Getting wrong timezone/date from PHP

Tags: php, date, xampp, timezone

When I echo the `date_default_timezone_get();` & `phpinfo();` I get Europe/Berlin when I should be getting America/New_York.

I have set `date.timezone = 'America/New_York'` in the PHP ini file, made sure the semicolon was removed from the beginning, and then I stoped and started the Apache server through the XAMPP control panel window.

I echo the `date_default_timezone_get();` and the `phpinfo();` and it is still set to Europe/Berlin

Any thoughts as to why this is?

Comment: Which `php.ini` file did you edit? There are often multiple copies for example, web and CLI. The output of `phpinfo()` should also tell you which `.ini` files are being used

Comment: I edited the one at  C:\xampp\php\php.ini , this path is also next to "Loaded Configuration File" in phpinfo() 

But next to "Configuration File (php.ini) Path"   it says "No Value"  could this be the issue ?

Also would "C:\xampp\php\php.ini " be Web or CLI ? excuse my lack of knowledge completely new to learning php (first programming language)

Comment: It's web,

After doing some digging i noticed that PHP is missing from the registry Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node 

Maybe i should re-install  XAMPP ?

Comment: @Phil I uninstalled and re-installed XAMPP but the registry is still missing PHP, and it still wont take the timezone i set in the PHP.ini file. Also the field next to "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" in phpinfo() is empty. Sorry i just seen how to tag people

Comment: @Phil Have any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Sorry no, I've never used XAMPP. These days I just use the [Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) if I need to do any bespoke PHP work

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why this happened, but i ended up installing php locally without XAMPP and its working now.